# How do I split command output by space or tab?

Tags: ruby, arrays, split, grep

I'm trying to do:

```
input = %x{netstat -ano | grep ^:80}
input.gsub(/\s+\t/m,' ').strip.split(" ")
puts input[4]
```

But I get the output of:  `C`, where I expected `<pid>`
The example output of just the netstat command is:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1800
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8081           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       8780
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8085           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5540
```

Additionally, I'm unsure of how to make `grep` match *exactly* `80` (or any other port I specify).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plain split without arguments will already do what you want:

```
input.lines.map do |line|
  proto, local, foreign, state, pid = line.split
  pid
end
#=> ["1800", "8780", "5540"]
```

You code has several problems that I want to point out though, maybe you can learn something from this:

- you are using `gsub` and `strip` which never actually changes `input`. You might want to use `gsub!` and `strip!` (mutators) for that purpose. `split` however has no mutator equivalent, because its return value is an array and not a string.
- `input[4]` simply gives you the fourth character of the `input` string

Answer (score 1):

You can match `80` and not, say, `8080` by matching word boundaries.

```
grep '\<80\>'
```

But if you're using Ruby, why screw around with grep at all? Just use regexps! Ruby's syntax for that is slightly different:

```
/\b80\b/
```